# Does ARC deallocate a class if deinit has been declared or does it maintain the reference?

Tags: swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to wrap my head around using ARC and the way it handles deallocation of memory. If I have some class:

```
class Person {
      var name: String = ""
      var age: Int = 0

      init(name: String, age: Int) {
         self.name = name
         self.age = age
     }

     deinit {
         print("Person \(name) has been deallocated")
     }
}



class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var person = Person(name: "Steve", age: 85)
}
```

Do I need to worry about freeing up the space for the person or does ARC handle it? Do I need to declare a `deinit` in `MyViewController`?

Comment: Just as with init, *deinit has **no effect** on the object’s lifetime*: “A deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is deallocated.” — see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html which also links to general ARC documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC handles deinitialization and deallocation for you once the referencing object is itself deallocated. Quoting from https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html:

> …ARC tracks how many properties, constants, and variables are currently referring to each class instance. ARC will not deallocate an instance as long as at least one active reference to that instance still exists.

> …whenever you assign a class instance to a property, constant, or variable, that property, constant, or variable makes a *strong reference* to the instance. The reference is called a “strong” reference because it keeps a firm hold on that instance, and doesn’t allow it to be deallocated for as long as that strong reference remains.

Your code demonstrates this as well: if I copy your code into a playground and add `MyViewController()` to create an instance of the class, I see `Person Steve has been deallocated` in the console output before the program exits.

Comment: One point of clarification on your excellent answer: The system does not always release and deallocate your objects before terminating your app. If your app is suspended and then terminated while suspended, it likely won't get its objects released/deallocated before the app is terminated.

Comment: (The lifecycle for playgrounds is quite different than that for apps, so you have to be a little careful using playgrounds as a way to test things about apps.)

Comment: That’s true. I also didn’t mention autorelease pools, which can cause delayed deallocation.

Comment: Great answer @jtbandes! That makes more sense!

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC for the clarification! How do you release/deallocate instances in your application to avoid it from maintaining that reference though? Is there a way to prevent your scenario from happening?

Comment: You don't need to do anything differently in your code as written. App terminations may not be ideal, but they are not entirely unexpected and the system may terminate your app whenever it deems necessary: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reduce-terminations-in-your-app  I would add that your `deinit`ializers may not be run during **abnormal** or forcible termination, but I would expect them to run in a normal scenario where the system first calls `applicationWillTerminate`.

Comment: The point of ARC is that you don't need to think about allocation and deallocation, because the compiler and runtime manage reference counting for you and deallocate when no references remain (a form of garbage collection). You only need to think about the strong and weak references and ensure there are no [retain cycles](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID51) in the object graph. If you find you need more control, you can use explicit `autoreleasepool`s and set optional references to `nil` when you are done using an object.

Comment: @jtbandes okay makes sense, but do you need to declare a deinit for every class instance then? I see a lot of examples with singletons where developers don't use deinit. How do you handle deallocation in those scenarios?

Comment: [deinit](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html) does not deallocate an object. It is called automatically _immediately before_ deallocation (like a destructor in C++). You only need to write one if you want to perform some logic when your object is being deallocated (or clean up any resources such as file handles that are not managed by ARC). Whether or not you write a custom deinit, the language will still take care of releasing weak/strong references held in any instance variables.

Comment: @jtbandes ahhhh that is what I was missing okay perfect! Thank you for the helpful insight

Comment: And if the system kills your app, it eliminates its entire memory space - stack, heap, the whole kit and caboodle. In that case deallocating individual heap objects is irrelevant - A bit like making sure you empty the trash-cans in your house before it's dynamited.

Comment: @jtbandes, the thing is, the "normal" scenario is actually not that normal anymore. `applicationWillTerminate` is rarely called before your app is terminated. You get suspended when the user switches to another app, and then terminated silently at some future time without  further warning.

Comment: That makes sense since the OS has been so heavily optimized over the years to reduce power consumption. But are you speaking from personal experience, or did Apple say this in documentation or a talk somewhere?